# pass gridview to another page ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a page that i use search in it and i want to pass the grid view to a result page after clicking on the button?
this button is search button and this code is working in default.aspx.cs with no problem but when ever i removed the grid and put it in the results.aspx i have an error in the last 3 lines.
    default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchby;
        searchby = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string str = string.Empty;
    switch (searchby)        {
        case "Search By":
            str = "select * from UserInfo u inner join TeamDB T on U.EMC_ID = T.EMC_ID where u.Name like '%' + @search + '%'";
                break;
        case "EMC ID":
            int searchID = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

            str = "select U.EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone ,T.Department ,T.TeamName , T.ManagerName, T.ManagerID from UserInfo U inner join TeamDB T on U.EMC_ID = T.EMC_ID where U.EMC_ID =" + searchID;
            break;
        case "Name":
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone from UserInfo where Name like '%' + @search + '%'";
            break;
        case "Email":
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone from UserInfo where Email like '%' + @search + '%'";
            break;
        case "Provider":
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone, Provider ,DataSIM, DataLineNumber, Data_IMEA from UserInfo where Provider like '%' + @search + '%'";
            break;
        case "USB Data Sim":
            Int64 searchSIM = Int64.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone, Provider ,DataSIM, DataLineNumber, Data_IMEA from UserInfo where DataSIM  =" + searchSIM;
            break;
        case "USB Data line Number":
            Int64 searchLine = Int64.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone, Provider ,DataSIM, DataLineNumber, Data_IMEA from UserInfo where DataLineNumber  =" + searchLine;
            break;
        case "USB Data IMEA":
            Int64 searchIMEA = Int64.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone, Provider ,DataSIM, DataLineNumber, Data_IMEA from UserInfo where Data_IMEA  =" + searchIMEA;

            break;
        case "Cisco Phone":
            int searchcisco = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            str = "select EMC_ID, Name, Email, CiscoPhone from UserInfo where CiscoPhone =" + searchcisco;

            break;
        case "Team Name":
            str = "select U.EMC_ID, U.Name, T.TeamName, T.ManagerID, T.ManagerName from UserInfo u inner join TeamDB T on U.EMC_ID = T.EMC_ID where T.TeamName like '%' + @search + '%'";
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please make a selection!");  
            break;
    }
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, did);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text; 

        did.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "EMC_ID");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
```

i want to redirect this code to open in a new page which is Results.aspx

Comment: i get another error in the str and textbox1.text  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, did);
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

            did.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "EMC_ID");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }

Comment: Telling us you got "another error" isn't very helpful when you fail to say what that error or the original error was.

Comment: i had no errors but i want to redirect the button on click to another page with the search results

Comment: You state in your question "I have an error in the last 3 lines" and then in a comment you say "I get another error" but now you're saying you had no errors? Which is it?

Comment: i did solve my problem with sessions and redirect thank you for your effort if you can't understand my question then do not answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement searching, and have the results show up on a search page? The solution then isn't to pass the GridView (which doesn't make sense because it's a UI element anyways) but instead to pass the search query, and perform the search on the results page. It should end up being something like this:

Search page

```
protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Results.aspx?search={0}",
        Server.UrlEncode(SearchTB.Text));
}
```

Results page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //run the query, bind results to GridView
    }
}
```

If you want an even better user interface, your searching and result displaying should all be done on one page, and you should use AJAX to send the search terms to the results and get them back.